# Akka group runForeach

Tags: scala, akka

I have an akka source that I want to group and run on batch. I am facing a problem and I am not really sure what is going wrong.

I have a source that looks something like this

```
val source = Source(facts.toList)
source
  .grouped(config.batchSize)
  .runForeach(batch => {
//Do something
  })
```

But I am getting

```
    [error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]
[error]       .runForeach(batch => {
[error]       

       ^
```

Why isn't it not able to run the source?

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the larger context in which your code snippet resides, but I'm guessing your code is the last expression inside a method that is expecting a return value of `Future[Unit]`. The compiler is complaining because `Source#runForeach` returns a `Future[Done]` instead of a `Future[Unit]`.

A quick fix could be to change your method's return type to `Future[Done]`.